# CKEditor with Bootstrap Skin precompile issue in Production for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am trying to use the bootstrap skin for ckeditor in rails 4. All works fine in development but I get a precompile error in production.

I added ckeditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). Then downloaded the bootstrap skin from (https://github.com/Kunstmaan/BootstrapCK4-Skin/tree/master/skins/bootstrapck)

I added the skin content in vendor/assests/javascript/ckeditor/skins

and added ckeditor to precompile array. Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )

In precompiling assets I get Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable error.

There are some scss files in the skin folder like vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck/scss/components/_colorpanel.scss
that have variables for example in above mentioned file there variable for colors like $gray (from bootstrap I suppose).

I think the scss files in the vendor folder cant access the variables and other scss from app/assets in precompile task.

Any idea how can I fix this, or is this actually the correct way of adding the extra skin in vendor folder?

rails 4.1.4 
sass-rails 4.0.4
ckeditor 4.1.1

appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
@import "../config/config";
```

at the top of most partials in

```
vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck/scss/components/
```

and

```
@import "colors";
```

at the top of

```
vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck/scss/config/_defaults.scss
```

to make it work.

It's not very DRY, but at least the skin assets will precompile.